# How do you pass ajax data to php $_POST?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the `$_POST['upload_id']` from ajax data. But every time I press submit, the error says `Undefined index: upload_id`
Here my code below:

```
$(".submit-comment-btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var upload_id= $(this).data("id_parent");
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"../Pages/user-feeds.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            upload_id:upload_id
        }
        
    });
});
```

The var `upload_id= $(this).data("id_parent");` gets the data-id from a button in a form

```
while($showPostRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($showPostQuery)){
 <form method='POST'>
     <div class='user-feeds-post-upload-comments-input'>                                       
        <textarea name='user-comment' placeholder='Write a comment...' rows='4' cols='80' ></textarea>
     </div>
      <div class='user-feeds-post-upload-comments-submit'>
         <button type='submit' name='submit-comment' class='submit-comment-btn' data-id_parent='".$showPostRow['upload_Id']."'>Upload</button>
     </div>
 </form>
}
```

And finally, this is my php code

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit-comment'])){
    $uploadComment= $_POST['user-comment'];
    $asd = $_POST['upload_id'];

    $postCommentQuery= "INSERT INTO `post_comments` (`parent_upload_Id`,`comment_text`, `comment_upload_time`, `user_Id`, `user_email`) 
    VALUES ('$asd','$uploadComment' ,current_timestamp(), '".$_SESSION['userid']."', '".$_SESSION['userEmail']."');";

    mysqli_query($conn,$postCommentQuery);
}
```

Whenever I try to submit it, it returns an error where it says `Undefined index: upload_id`

Comment: In POST is just `upload_id`. Other variables aren't passed to PHP (line 9 in first code snippet)

Comment: try the following steps: do a dump of all POST data to see what it's receiving.
console log $(this).data("id_parent"); before submitting the data, to see wether it's actually been set the way you expect

Comment: I tried putting " " in ajax data.

data{ "upload_id" : upload_id} but it still doesn't work

Comment: @pavel so it should just be data:{upload_id}?

Comment: It still doesn't work. upload_id is still undefined. I tried to alert the var upload_id, and it did alert the ID that I was looking for. But it wasn't passed to $_POST['upload_id']

Comment: Please study AJAX basics. Your code can't work, `$_POST['submit-comment']` in undefined if form is sent via AJAX (than you can't get warning 'undefined index ...' beacuse you're not inside that condition). Or you're inside, than `$_POST['submit-comment']` is set, form isn't sent via AJAX and than `$_POST['upload_id']` is undefined because there in form there is no field with `name="upload_id"`.

Comment: You have no `success` or `done` handler for your AJAX request so how can you see what the response is?

Comment: Make sure the value of `$showPostRow['upload_Id']` exists. I also see an uppercase i in the `upload_Id`, you might want to check on it and see if it really is the correct key to retrieve the upload id.

Comment: firstly `echo $showPostRow['upload_Id'];` check whether exists or not then `console.log($(this).data("id_parent"));` , and also you haven't add any success or done handler in your ajax. then in php check `print_r($_POST);`